# Is it safe to upgrade to Yosemite when using VMWare Fusion 6?

Tags: macos, vmware, virtualization, windows

I'm currently running OS X 10.9.5. Within that I have Windows 8 running in VMWare Fusion 6.0.4 for some critical (but Windows only unfortunately) applications that I use daily.

Is it safe to upgrade to Yosemite and still run Fusion 6? Will my Windows 8 VM continue to function as normal?

My reason for asking is that I've seen a few threads elsewhere where people have had issues with beta versions of Yosemite and Fusion 6. I'm hoping that these issues have been ironed out by now?

There is now VMWare Fusion 7 which is supposedly "Ready for Yosemite" and I'm happy to upgrade but wondered if anyone has had any negative experiences that I should be wary of e.g. losing data, not being able to start the VM etc.

If not, should I upgrade the OS first and then Fusion or vice versa? Or should I just stop worrying because it'll probably all be fine?!

I can't afford to lose half a day restoring from backup because upgrading has messed my VM up so thought best to check.

Answer (score 3):

The latest version of VMWare 6 is now OK with Yosemite.

Previous versions would not even run if the system was upgraded to Yosemite.

I would recommend upgrading VMWare to the latest version of v6 (currently 6.0.5) first, then upgrading the system to Yosemite. That way, when you boot into the new system, you should not have any problems with VMWare not running.

Answer (score 1):

I do not recommend updating to Yosemite with VMWare Fusion 6 unless you have received an update stating that it has been fixed.

Otherwise you might have to upgrade to 7 as I know it works with Yosemite and has support as well.

Also you might want to try contacting VMWare or you can try finding your query in the knowledge base for more info...

[Support Link Here!](http://www.vmware.com/support.html)

[Search Knowledge Base Here!](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/microsite.do;jsessionid=9CE968BC676BCECECE4A013D87683AD0)

Answer (score 0):

no!
you must upgrade VMware first. else you WILL get a disk error when installing Yosemite

Answer (score 0):

I've upgraded to yosemite first and had VMWare 6.0.1 installed and sure enough it wasn't working after the OS upgrade. I then upgraded VMWare Fusion to 6.0.5 and although my VMs are working now, networking is not!
I cannot access networks from any of my VMs and cannot make any changes to network settings. Everything is greyed out, even when the VM is down.
I'm using Windows 7 and a debian based Linux distribution as VM.

It appears that VMWare Fusion 6 (even the last version) is not entirely ready for Yosemite! I have not tried VMWare 7 yet.

Comment: I have exactly your problem: Mac networking freezes the moment VMware 6.0.5 loads. Even starting Terminal and running 'netstat -a' fails - it just hangs. But bizarrely, I can start a Windows 7 VM and access the network perfectly. The Mac remains frozen.